# Set app to send an SMS MESSAGE when time set is reached

Tags: java, android, sms, alarmmanager, smsmanager

the user sets a date and time (both editText) and when the exact time reaches, the app pulls the time and date and compares it to the present time, and then, it is supposed to send a text, however when the time comes, nothing happens. 
This is the snippet of my code that does that:

```
Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar alarmdate=Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
String a,b;
Date duedate;

dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
String hour= String.valueOf(today.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    String minute= String.valueOf(today.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    String todaytime=hour+ " : " + minute;
    String alarmtime=tvtime.getText().toString();

try {
        duedate=dateFormatter.parse(tvdate.getText().toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    alarmdate.setTime(duedate);

a=dateFormatter.format(today.getTime());
    b=dateFormatter.format(alarmdate.getTime());
    if(today.equals(alarmdate)){
        if (todaytime.equals(alarmtime)){
            sendSMS(numbertotext,message);
        }
    }
}

private void sendSMS(String number, String message) {
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(),0);
    SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(number,null,message,pi,null);
}
```

i was thinking about using alarmmanager but how would that work? Would the SMS code be in the Alarm.java? and how? Please any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create AlarmReceiver
   Permission required:

   public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     //send sms from here
   }
   ```

   }
2. Set an alarm

   AlarmManager alarm;
               PendingIntent intent;
               Intent otherIntent = new Intent();
               otherIntent.setClass(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
               alarm = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
               intent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
                       (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), otherIntent,
                       PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
               alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SCHEDULED_TIME, intent);

Store all the scheduled messages in the database and from the AlarmReceiver, fetch all the messages from the database whose scheduled time <= current time.
Another thing you might require is to handle the case when the mobile phone is off at the time of the alarm, in that case start a service on boot completed and send all pending messages.

For alarm example, refer: https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK/blob/master/mobicomkit/src/main/java/com/applozic/mobicomkit/api/conversation/schedule/ScheduledMessageUtil.java

Comment: thank you! will try it out and watch it for 24 hours and update you if it works!